# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, permissions, laravel-5.8

I just added a directory to my `public` directory of Laravel 5.8 project which is on Live Server but faced this error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

And at the `public` directory I have this as `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 300
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Disable TRACE, TRACK & OPTIONS
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS) 
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

So how can I load this directory properly in this Laravel project?

Comment: Laravel is running on VPS or shared hosting?

Comment: @EHFShahab Shared hosting but has ssl activated

Comment: Set public directory and sub directories permission to 755

Comment: @EHFShahab I think it assumes that my folder name is a reserved keyword, it must be something related to the htaccess

Comment: @EHFShahab It is already set to 755

Comment: And the owner is you?

Comment: @EHFShahab No but I have access to the direct admin as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247258/discussion-between-ehf-shahab-and-pouya).

Comment: Along with the correct permissions, ensure that the owner and group of the directory you created is correct.